# MySQL count error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to count all rows within the column field_161. However, it just returns the value of 0. The connection to the database is successful and the table and row are spelled correctly.

Here's my code:

```
$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_entity_21 WHERE field_161 = 30 as $mytotaltasks");
echo "test" . $mytotaltasks;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't just do `AS $mytotaltasks` in mysql, and turn it into a PHP variable. You'll need to get the result from the query. The simplest way is to use [`fetchColumn()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php):

```
$query = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_entity_21 WHERE field_161 = 30");
$mytotaltasks = $query->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working and instead just displays a completely blank white page.

Comment: @LouisDench Check your error logs, and comment back with the error.

Comment: @LouisDench This code doesn't echo out anything. Add `echo "Count: " . $mytotaltasks;` at the end of your script to display the count.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add the Group By at then end of query string

```
$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app_entity_21 WHERE field_161 = 30 group by field_161");
```

echo "test" . $mytotaltasks;

Answer (score -2):

Try this!

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(field_161)AS field_cont FROM app_entity_21 WHERE field_161 = 30 as $mytotaltasks");

$data_cont=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

echo "This is the number of rows". $data_cont['field_cont'];
```

or a little bit different:

```
$result=$conn->query("SELECT COUNT(field_161)AS field_cont FROM app_entity_21 WHERE field_161 = 30 as $mytotaltasks");

$data_cont=mysqli_fetch_object($result);

echo "This is the number of rows". $data_cont->field_cont;
```

Comment: Why would you switch from object to procedural syntax?

Comment: I was just trying to show options,  I didn't mean switch from one to another. by the way answer is the easier way. cheers

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_object($result);` could be written as `$result->fetch_object()`

Comment: True. Thx for the advice I'm a beginner in php. Really useful tip.

Comment: `as $mytotaltasks` is invalid syntax, both your quires would fail